# Software for finding a closed formula from a list of triples of positive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, integers, math-software

Suppose we have a finite list of $n$ triples of positive integer numbers, as:

$$
  \mathcal{L}=\{(a_{i1},a_{i2},a_{i3}):a_{ij}\in \mathbf{N}\setminus\{0\}, \text{ for } j=1,2,3\}_{i=1,\dots,n}.\
$$

Is there a software, where I can give $\mathcal{L}$ as in-put and which gives as out-put a possible formula, denoted by $F(a_{i2},a_{13})$, such that $a_{i1}=F(a_{i2},a_{13})$ (it could be not existing or it is not unique)? This formula can involve any operations of sum, multiplication, power, division, or also integer parts or binomial coefficients.

Just two examples to be clearer.

1. Consider the following list of $3$-uple: $(5, 12, 13), (7, 24, 25), (8, 15, 17), (20, 21, 29)$. They are Pythagorean triples and  $a_{i1} = \sqrt{a_{i2}^2+a_{i3}^2}$, so $F(a_{i2},a_{13})=\sqrt{a_{i2}^2+a_{i3}^2}$ in such a case.
2. Consider: $(1,3,1), (2,4,1), (3,5,1)$. Then two possible formulas are $F(a_{i2},a_{13})=\mathrm{floor}(\frac{a_{i2}-2}{a_{i3}})$ or $F(a_{i2},a_{13})=a_{i2}-2a_{i3}$.

If $n>>0$, which means that we have a lot of triples, so the the formula $F(a_{i2},a_{13})$ should be unique, or in any case we can have just few of it (if it exists).

Comment: What about training a deep neural network with a_i2 and a_i3 as inputs and a_i1 as output? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

Comment: I don't know how I can do that unfortunately... Do you suggest some deep neural network in particular? Chat GPT 3.5 isn't able to do it

Comment: Are you versed in any programming language?

Comment: Not in any programming language, unfortunately I'm not used to program in Python. Why that? Could it be a problem?

Comment: If you knew Python, then I could have directed you to a Python library for neural nets. You can look into regressions instead.

Comment: Did you mean to use some suitable software for regressions?

Comment: Yes. You might like to see the one supported in Desmos.

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't useful :(